# Is it better to name the primary key column id or *_id?

Tags: sql

I've been using Rails for a few years and I've grown used to the convention of naming the primary key column `id`. But I've run across lots of examples in SQL books that name the primary key column something like `employee_id` for an `employees` table or `feed_id` for a `feeds` table.

One advantage of the 2nd system seems to be that you can use `USING()` more to produce more concise SQL queries:

```
select feeds.title, items.title from items inner join feeds USING(feed_id);
```

As opposed to

```
select feeds.title, items.title from items inner join feeds on feeds.id = items.feed_id;
```

Which naming convention is better? Which is favored by experienced database administrators?

Also, is it better to pluralize the name of the table?

Comment: Sorry, but this is just too subjective. I'd say do what works best for you and don't worry about what the popular consensus is.

Comment: @Brady Asking `what's better` is subjective. If he asked, what is the standard database naming convention for referencing fields, that would be different. The original question implies that both are acceptable, but he wants to know what everyone else is doing because their way is semantically`better` in some regard.

Comment: I have no problem with the question. It obviously is one of those "best practice" types of question. It may be true that both ways are okay, but it should be part of answer, not the criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablename_Id is my strong preference. When you do joins to Fks you know exactly what to join to what and don't make mistakes where you join to ID in table a when you meant tableb below is an example of how easy this is to do especially if you copy the on clause from somewhere else

```
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b
  ON a.ID = b.tableaid
JOIN tablec c
  ON a.ID = c.tablebid
```

In the case above, you really wanted to join to B.Id but forgot to change it from a when you copied. It will work and give you a resultset that isn't correct. If you use table_id instead, the query would fail the syntax check.

Another problem with using Id is when you are doing complex reports. Since the repport queries have to have fields with individual names, you can end up wasting time writing a bunch of aliases you wouldn't need if you had named the id with the tablename.

Now people who use ORMs don't write a lot of SQl but what they do write and what report writers write are generally complex, complicated statements. You need to design you database to make it easier to do those things than simple queries.

The use of ID as the name for the identifying field is considered a SQl antipattern. [http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1308929815&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

Comment: I have that book -- do you remember what page or chapter this antipattern is mentioned?

Comment: @dan, I don't have page numbers in my ebook, but it is Chapter 4 the section called: Obscuring the Meaning of the Key

Comment: I don't see how failure to rename a.ID to b.ID is any different than failure to rename a.a_ID to b.b_ID. I understand it adds some redundancy that can lead to less typos, but come on... redundancy in coding is good?

Comment: @Josef Sábl, because you are more likley tonotice that tablenameid is wrong than just using id. It is an antipattern. I suspect you have never worked with actual complex reporting coding or you would see that right off. When you have 20 or mor joins to get the reporting information you want, the extra clarity is critical.

Comment: @HLGEM But I disagree with this solution nowadays! I prefer use Id instead of xxxId or xxx_Id. when you have Intellisense in modern Dbs (like SQL 2008 and above) and you have table identifier why we should add redundant data? use Customers.Id instead of Id whenever needed. It is more Concident to OOP naming conventions too.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej, OOP naming conventions are irrelvant so is Intellisense.

Comment: Don't design database like you desgn OOP applications.

Answer (score 7):

I always use the verbose form (i.e. 'employee_id' rather than 'id') as it is more descriptive.  If you are joining more than one table and both have 'id' column you will have to alias 'id' if you need to SELECT both of the ids.  Also, as you mentioned, you get the advantage of USING clause.  In the grand scheme of things it isn't a huge factor one way or the other but the more verbose form gives you advantages.

Answer (score 4):

Both options are valid but the purists will say use id as its name is specified by the table.

I use table_id because I find it to be more descriptive and makes debugging easier.  It's more practical.

Re: Tablenames.  Another hotly debated topic among database nerds but I say Singular.

Answer (score 2):

This is user preference, but I always name the primary keys of my tables `Id`.  I always name references of that Id in other tables as [SingularEntityName][Id] e.g.

```
Credentials
Id    Password

Users
Id    Name  CredentialId

Descriptions
Id  UserId
```

Keeps my references clean.  However, just be consistant in your naming and it really shouldn't matter how you set up your schemas.

Answer (score 2):

To open the can of worms again,
I'm willing to bet those who select tablename_id are older, more experienced programmers.
Those who use just id are younger.

Why ?  because you learn redundancy and constancy is not always a bad thing.
the one thing I would add to the #1 answer, use the "_" helps make it easier to pick out the variable in code, in the table, etc...  I do the same for foreign keys.  TableName_FK  Some will argue over that but it works for me and it's obvious what it is.

I have had to work on other's code many times over the years.  Consistency is critical, obfuscation is worthless and meaningful variable names very helpful. 
There are those who argue that verbosity makes code harder to read.  I don't think that argument flies in today's world of objects.that.derive.from.some.microsoft.class.twenty.layers.deep.that.you.have.to.fully.reference.

BTW - as so many have said, it's your choice.  Those folks who spend time arguing over coding syntax don't have enough work to do.  Learn to be flexible and to use the standards of the workplace where you are employed.  If you are lucky enough to set your own standards, then have at it.  The fact your are wondering is great.  But choose one and then be consistent (until you change jobs or decide you have a paradigm shift that means you want to change your style.)

You can often pick out what era someone started learning to code by their personal preferences and styles.  Guys that write very tight, minmal, hard to read code, started back when memory was very limited (DOS) and probably wrote a lot of assembler, those that use Hungarian started back with the Win SDK, etc...

This discussion has been evolving for decades.  The older I get, the more I document my code, the more meaningful I make my variable names, etc...  because in a week I will have forgotten what I wrote and I need the road maps to make sense of it.  Not so much that I'm forgetful, although that's part of the equation, but more so because I'm writing code on so many different projects.

Answer (score 0):

it's entirely your choice. But personally I prefer the second one as I wouldn't need to look for table names in my code when I come across an id. I think tablename_id is better.

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage to giving your primary keys names that are unique to that table is that it makes it easier to have a naming convention, when referring to those keys in different tables, that indicates the corresponding key.

For example, suppose everything in your alpha table begins alpha_, so that you have alpha_id as your primary key.  In your beta table - where everything would begin beta_ - you would use beta_alpha_id to have a reference in that table to the keys in the alpha table.

Comment: sorry, beta_alpha_id is overkill. Alpha_id in beta table is more clear. In SQL you can use aliases to bypass problem if same column_name stay in more tables.